# How do I give swagger my dto with default value?

Tags: c#

In .NET Core API, I have a controller with an action method called `Add`:

```
[Route("[action]")]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Add(DTO.User dtoModel)
{
    var entity = _mapper.Map<Entity.User>(dtoModel);
    entity.IsDeleted = false;

    unitOfWork.User.Insert(entity);
    unitOfWork.Complete();

    return Ok(entity);
}
```

My class DTO.User has properties called `status` and `gender`.

I want to set `Status = false`, `Gender = "male"`

I did it in the constructor:

```
 public User()
 {
     this.Status = false;
     this.Gender = "Male";
 }
```

but it gives me gender = "string" and status = true ?

Comment: Tag your properties with a [DefaultValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute?view=net-7.0) attribute.  Whatever Swagger generator you use it should pick that up.

Comment: You could answer the question so it does not stay open. I found another solution for this but did not post as this one is definitely the simplest out there ! I mean, I'd vote for that one

Answer (score 1):

Tag your properties with a DefaultValue attribute. Whatever Swagger generator you use it should pick that up. –
Ralf